# Heroku / Django failing to load GDAL library

Tags: django, heroku, gis, gdal

I'm trying to import the GDAL library in a Django project, and while my application loads successfully locally, and builds successfully when deploying to Heroku, it crashes once the web server starts.

Using the buildpack https://github.com/TrailStash/heroku-geo-buildpack

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn feed.wsgi`
app[web.1]: [2018-07-15 13:24:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
app[web.1]: [2018-07-15 13:24:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:55791 (4)
app[web.1]: [2018-07-15 13:24:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
app[web.1]: [2018-07-15 13:24:39 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
app[web.1]: [2018-07-15 13:24:39 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
app[web.1]: [2018-07-15 13:24:40 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/feed/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
app[web.1]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
app[web.1]:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
app[web.1]:     app_config.import_models()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
app[web.1]:     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/core/models.py", line 4, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis.db import models
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
app[web.1]:     import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py", line 3, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from .fields import (  # NOQA
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 2, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from .collections import (  # NOQA
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py", line 9, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 8, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis import gdal
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 47, in <module>
app[web.1]:     lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
app[web.1]:     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
app[web.1]: OSError: $HOME/.heroku/vendor/lib/libgdal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
app[web.1]: [2018-07-15 13:24:40 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Followed by a Gunicorn halt server exception

I found a fork of this buildpack where `APP_VENDOR_RUNTIME` was modified to correct a typo (`APP_VENDOR_RUNTIME="$\HOME/$TARGET_VENDOR_DIR"` to `$HOME`), which didn't fix things. I then forked it myself and changed `$HOME` to `/app/`, to no avail. Curiously, this gives the same error (in that it still references `$HOME/.heroku/vendor/lib/libgdal.so`).

libgdal.so is confirmed to exist, used `chmod` to give all users read access to no avail.

Hardcoding the libraries as strings (rather than environment variables) did have some difference, failing at build instead of run:

```
-----> geos/gdal/proj app detected
   Using geos version: 3.6.1
   Using gdal version: 2.1.3
   Using proj version: 4.9.3
export GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/build_4a3351bf23a32eaf56d29213aa25e2b5/.heroku/vendor/lib/libgeos_c.so
export GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/build_4a3351bf23a32eaf56d29213aa25e2b5/.heroku/vendor/lib/libgdal.so
export PROJ4_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/build_4a3351bf23a32eaf56d29213aa25e2b5/.heroku/vendor/lib
export GDAL_DATA=/tmp/build_4a3351bf23a32eaf56d29213aa25e2b5/.heroku/vendor/share/gdal
export LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/build_4a3351bf23a32eaf56d29213aa25e2b5/.heroku/vendor/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/build_4a3351bf23a32eaf56d29213aa25e2b5/.heroku/vendor/lib
export CPATH=/tmp/build_4a3351bf23a32eaf56d29213aa25e2b5/.heroku/vendor/include
export PATH=/tmp/build_4a3351bf23a32eaf56d29213aa25e2b5/.heroku/vendor/bin:$PATH
-----> Vendoring geo libraries done
-----> Python app detected
   Skipping installation, as Pipfile.lock hasn't changed since last deploy.
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
       utility.execute()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
       django.setup()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
       app_config.import_models()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
     File "/tmp/build_4a3351bf23a32eaf56d29213aa25e2b5/core/models.py", line 4, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis.db import models
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
       import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py", line 3, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
       from .fields import (  # NOQA
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 2, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
       from .collections import (  # NOQA
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py", line 9, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 8, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis import gdal
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
       from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 72, in <module>
       _version_info = std_call('GDALVersionInfo')
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 66, in std_call
       return lgdal[func]
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
       func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
   AttributeError: /app/.heroku/vendor/lib/libgeos_c.so: undefined symbol: GDALVersionInfo
!     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
   See traceback above for details.
   You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
   Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
      $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed
```

Environment variables are set as so:

```
 GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH - /app/.heroku/vendor/lib/libgdal.so
 GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH - /app/.heroku/vendor/lib/libgeos_c.so
 PROJ4_LIBRARY_PATH - /app/.heroku/vendor/lib/libproj.so
```

Any ideas?

Comment: After further digging I realised I couldn't import GDAL from a python shell either, so I made the decision to switch this project to a Docker container instead